# R: How to create dynamic subsets of data.table with a paired sequence of start, end row sequences

Tags: r, data.table

I.E. Splitting Data Table into dynamic quantity of variable chunks based off of row index

I am trying to split a data.table into chunks by row index.

The data is dynamic and the number of chunks may change & vary in size.

For example:

MyDT is a 2675 row, 98 column data table.

I've determined that for this dataset that I want rows 3-796, 802-857, 936-952, and 1206-2623 as their own separate chunks that I can call/save as a separate variable/etc.

I want the script to be dynamic and not require manual inputting of indexes. I can find any length and quantity of chunks currently, I just can't export them into a clean array/list. I.e. chunk 1 is DAT[1] , chunk 2 is DAT[2], and so on

[Background for the curious, I am importing data into R from an instrument that outputs its data from multiple experiments into a "messy" text file. I am separating the numeric, matrix form data from the rest of the cluttered output. Sometimes my data file has info from 2 experiments, 3, 4, etc...]

Comment: If it s a data.table.  It can be just `MyDT[3:796];MyDT[802:857]` and so on

Comment: akrun ; thank you for responding. That approach is my final method but I want the script to be dynamic and not require such manual editing. I can find any length and quantity of chunks currently, I just can't export them into a clean array/list. I.e. chunk 1 is DAT[1] , chunk 2 is DAT[2], and so on.

Comment: Is there any pattern in those ranges, then it could be made dynamic.  But, if those numbers 3-796, 802-857, etc seems to be custom range

Comment: Akrun ; there is no pattern in those ranges. However, I can make two arrays that describe the "start" and "end" indexes for each chunk of data. Every dataset will have a variable number of chunks of differing length

Comment: In that case it is more easier i.e. `Map(function(i, j) MyDT[i:j], v1, v2)` where v1 and v2 are the start, end vectors.  The output of `Map` is a `list` of subset of data.tables, which you can store

Comment: @akrun ; genius. That's exactly the type of method I was looking for and could not find over many hours of looking/reading. Can you please post that as an answer so that I may tag this question as answered? Also I happy to take suggestions on how to modify my question such that I improve the score. I think others may find your advice helpful

Comment: Your question can be modified by asking focused question i.e. How to create subset of data.table with a paired sequence of start, end row sequences

Comment: @akrun  ; I have made the suggested edit. I thought my original title was quite defined & descriptive; however, I appreciate that I am not active in the community and thus likely don't know the accepted terminology for such descriptions. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to store it in a `list`, create a sequence of 'start', 'end' vectors, use that to subset the data.table with `Map`

```
library(data.table)
start <- c(3, 802, 936, 1206)
end <- c(796, 857, 952, 2623)
lst_out <- Map(function(i, j) MyDT[i:j], start, end)
```